# git-http-backend with AuthzUnixGroup not working properly

Tags: git, apache, centos, centos6

I am trying to set up a git repository over my Apache 2.2 on a CentOS 6 box, with git installed. I have tried following many different directions, and I am at a loss. My current situation comprises of being able to `clone` normally, but being completely unable to push.

It seems as though I am incapable of getting the authentication bit to work properly, as I can normally perform the push while setting `http.receivepack` to `true`.

I have installed `AuthzUnixGroup` as well as `mod_authz_external`.

I went to `/var/www/git` and created a repo named `my-repo.git` and did a `git init --bare` inside it.

Then I set up my `git.conf` file inside `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost "*:80">
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
  SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
  SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
  ScriptAlias /git /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
  AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/local/libexec/pwauth
  SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe

  <Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location "/git">
    AuthzUnixGroup on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git repository"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
    Require group git
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Pointing my web browser to `mysite/git` nicely shows me the HTTP basic login dialog, which works perfectly. I have added myself to the group `git`, and doing a `groups` on my shell returns:

```
naseri sudo git
```

which is as expected.

When I do `git clone http://mysite/git/my-repo.git` I get the following from the access_log file for httpd under `/var/logs/httpd/access_log`:

```
2.177.130.21 - - [11/Jun/2014:18:51:07 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 480 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
2.177.130.21 - - [11/Jun/2014:18:51:08 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 480 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
2.177.130.21 - naseri [11/Jun/2014:18:51:08 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 256 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
2.177.130.21 - naseri [11/Jun/2014:18:51:09 +0000] "POST /git/my-repo.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 368 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
```

On the client, the `clone`ing works properly. I change stuff around, then try to push after a commit by `git push`ing the content.

This is what I get on the server side log:

```
2.177.130.21 - - [11/Jun/2014:18:53:26 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 480 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
2.177.130.21 - naseri [11/Jun/2014:18:53:27 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 480 "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
2.177.130.21 - naseri [11/Jun/2014:18:53:30 +0000] "GET /git/my-repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "git/1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"
```

I can see that my "Authentication Required" response is being sent back by Apache on the first line of response (401) but the client shows me:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://mysite/git/my-repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am clueless as to the problem, as pointing my browser to the same URL properly brings up authentication and it even works right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [older answer](https://serverfault.com/a/190965/783)

> `git-http-backend` is returning a 403/Forbidden code when the client asks to use the git-receive-pack method.
>   It then falls back to WebDAV, **but using WebDAV is not necessary**.
>
> I had the same problem; in my case this was due to `REMOTE_USER` not being set

Since any of my [Apache config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl) uses an '`=`' when setting a variable, check if this works better:

```
SetEnv REMOTE_USER $REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
```

(no '`-`' between the two variables)

Check also if *not* (re)defining `REMOTE_USER` works too (because it might already been defined, while `REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER` might not): try without that line.
I never have to define it in my Apache Git config.

Note: [with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019, 5+ years later), Git should be more robust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058503/6309).

Comment: I tried it with and without a '=' and tried leaving it unspecified. No luck. Also, when checking out the code, it does not ask for my credentials, which I think is not the right way for this to work.

Comment: @MiladNaseri can you add a `Require valid-user` rule to see if it asks for your credentials this time?

Comment: The problem still persists. When checking out, the server sends two 401s and then responds with a 200, yielding the repository content.

Comment: I have not been able to fix this issue as of yet. Yet, yours is the only solution that attempts at a proper answer, and as promised, here goes your reward, though from a 2k to 403k user, it shouldn't count as much :-)

Comment: @MiladNaseri it does count,  a lot :-) but I will try to do some more tests with your config, and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: :) Great. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in situation like this, and found that trying to use Apache to serve git is anything but easy or simple.

Instead, I would recommend installing [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit) - it allows to host multiple repositories, and most importantly has extremely flexible user/group management and permission model. As a nice bonus, it also happens to be very powerful code review engine, but it is completely optional - you don't have to use code review features if you don't want to.

Other known solutions for this are [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com) and [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com) - you might want to look into them as well.